# Laravel 9: authenticate while running a command

Tags: laravel, php-8

Here is an example of Laravel command:

```
class TestUserCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'test:user';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function handle(): void
    {
        auth('api')->loginUsingId(1);

        ... domain service call
    }
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
 Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::loginUsingId does not exist.
```

What I want to do is authenticate so I can then initiate some complex business logic, that internally retrieves current user like so:

```
return auth('api')->check() ? auth('api')->user() : null;
```

Here is my **auth.php** configuration:

```
   'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

UPD: What worked for me as temporary solution is `Passport::actingAs()`, but it does not seem to be meant for production.

Comment: can you use `Auth::loginUsingId(1)` instead of `auth('api')->loginUsingId(1)` ?

Comment: @KavanPrajapati I tried, but in this case `auth('api')->check()` returns false

Comment: yes, you also need to change with `Auth::check()` instead of auth('api')->check() and `Auth::user()` in place of auth('api')->user()

Comment: So you don't actually want to authenticate the user running the command? You should clarify the question to make it clear you just want to fake the authentication. Why not just rewrite the other code to handle command line usage properly?

Comment: laravel version?

Comment: @francisco it's 9

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Auth::attempt()` and use prompt to get mail and password like,

```
public function handle() {
    $email = $this->ask('Email ?');
    $password = $this->secret('Password ?');

    $attempt = Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]);
    if($attempt) {
        $user = auth()->user();
    }
}
```

EDITED:
You couldn't able to use guard on `passport`, so duplicate the same guard with `session` like,

```
'api_with_session' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'users',
 ],
```

Then, you can able to login the user

```
auth('api_with_session')->loginUsingId(1);        
$user = auth('api_with_session')->user();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9, the `loginUsingId()` method is not available in the `RequestGuard` class, which is causing the error you encountered. Instead, you can use the `loginUsingId()` method provided by the `Auth` facade.

To ensure compatibility with future updates, I recommend using the login() method:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class TestUserCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'test:user';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function handle(): void
    {
        $user = \App\Models\User::find(1); // Replace with your user retrieval logic

        Auth::guard('api')->login($user);

        // ... domain service call
    }
}
```